# vba - printing worksheets in workbooks in folder

Tags: vba, excel, printing

With wb

```
Set Sh2 = .Sheets("sheet2)
    With Sh2.PageSetup
        .PrintArea = "$B$2:$S$80"
        .PaperSize = xlPaperLegal
    End With

Set Sh3 = .Sheets("sheet3")
    With Sh3.PageSetup
        .PrintArea = "$B$2:$M$104"
        .PaperSize = xlPaperLegal
        .Orientation = xlPortrait
    End With

Set execsum1 = .Sheets("sheet4")
    With execsum1.PageSetup
        .PrintArea = "$B$7:$N$63"
        .PaperSize = xlPaperLegal
        .Orientation = xlLandscape
        .PrintTitleRows = "$B$2:$N$6"
    End With

Set execsum2 = .Sheets("sheet5")
    With execsum2.PageSetup
        .PrintArea = "$B$64:$N$106"
        .PaperSize = xlPaperLegal
        .Orientation = xlLandscape
        .PrintTitleRows = "$B$2:$N$6"
    End With
    'ActiveSheet.PrintPreview

Set noi1 = .Sheets("sheet6")
    With noi1.PageSetup
        .PrintArea = "$B$10:$N$44"
        .PaperSize = xlPaperLegal
        .Orientation = xlLandscape
        .PrintTitleRows = "$B$2:$N$8"
        .FitToPagesTall = 1
    End With

Set noi2 = .Sheets("sheet7")
    With noi2.PageSetup
        .PrintArea = "$B$46:$N$192"
        .PaperSize = xlPaperLegal
        .Orientation = xlLandscape
        .PrintTitleRows = "$B$2:$N$8"
        '.FitToPagesWide = 1
        .FitToPagesTall = 1
    End With

End With

Dim sheet As Variant
For Each sheet In Array(execsum1, execsum2, Sh2, Sh3, noi1, noi2)
    sheet.PrintOut Copies:=1
Next

    'Save and Close Workbook
      'wb.Close SaveChanges:=False

    'Ensure Workbook has closed before moving on to next line of code
      DoEvents

    'Get next file name
      myFile = Dir
  Loop

'Message Box when tasks are completed
  MsgBox "Task Complete!"

ResetSettings:
  'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Hello all, I'm new to VBA and I'm trying to print 6 worksheets/pages per workbooks found in a folder. Execsum1 and execsum2 are from the same worksheet with different print areas; same story with noi1 and noi2. When I run the code, it prints out the second designated page twice (execsum2 and noi2). Why isn't execsum1/noi1 printing out and if possible, how can I make the code more efficient? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It prints the same sheet twice because you aren't printing the worksheet between changing the PageSetup from your first version to your second version.  You collect worksheet references here...

```
Set execsum1 = .Sheets("Exec Summary")
'...
Set execsum2 = .Sheets("Exec Summary")
```

...that are identical to each other. A worksheet only has 1 `PageSetup`, so when you do this...

```
For Each sheet In Array(execsum1, execsum2, Sh2, Sh3, noi1, noi2)
    sheet.PrintOut Copies:=1
Next
```

...you get the last thing it was set to.

Just skip the loop entirely and print each individually. There is absolutely no benefit to looping over them.

```
With execsum1.PageSetup
    .PrintArea = "$B$7:$N$63"
    .PaperSize = xlPaperLegal
    .Orientation = xlLandscape
    .PrintTitleRows = "$B$2:$N$6"
End With
execsum1.PrintOut Copies:=1   '<--- After each With block.
```

If you want to simplify the code, just extract out the common .PageSetup into a function, and pass everything else as a parameter (note that this is just an example - I didn't include everything you're using).  I.e.:

```
Private Sub PrintCustomRange(sheet As Worksheet, area As String, title As String, _
                             orient As XlPageOrientation, paper As XlPaperSize)
    With sheet.PageSetup
        .PrintArea = area
        .PaperSize = paper
        .Orientation = orient
        If Len(title) > 0 Then .PrintTitleRows = title
    End With
    .PrintOut Copies:=1
End Sub
```

Then call it like this:

```
PrintCustomRange Sheets("Proforma NOI"), "$B$46:$N$192", "$B$2:$N$8", xlLandscape, xlPaperLegal
```

Comment: @wowmoo - That sounds like something to do with the printer driver.